# How to use same objects at wordpress admin and user side?

Tags: php, wordpress

I started to create my first plugin for wordpress with admin pages and user page using OOP. At the "plugins" folder I created a new for my plugin. I have "index.php", an "includes" folder with some object php and "admin" folder. At the "themes" folder I created a new page-* php for the users. My problem, that **I can't use my objects at user side**. In the admin pages everything is fine, I can call and get datas, but in the page-*.php the /* @var $datas Object[] */ is don't do the same, $datas is NULL. How to link my admin and theme pages?
Thank for the help!

Comment: So you are trying to access the properties of an object in the frontend of wordpress that has been instantiated in admin ?

Comment: Yes. In the plugin folder have an includes folder (with classes and admin). The object created/edited in the admin main file.
Maybe I put the classes into the themes folder? I don't know yet wordpress structure what what can see.

Comment: Generally, a plugin is simply an extension of your theme's functions.php file, so any object that resides (and is included) in your plugin will be accessible in your frontend theme, provided you instantiate it. See [Initiate a class in a WP plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70055/best-way-to-initiate-a-class-in-a-wp-plugin)

Comment: The problem with this class call, that I don't need the functions in the class now. I have only a construct and some getter functions. I need the final object which content is the sql table all data. This created in the admin file with $images = new Photos(id, param1, param2, param3,... ); uploadPhotos($images);.
For list data $images = getPhotos(); get the data with sql query. After this I would like to use a foreach $images as $image and get values by $image->getParam().

Comment: Please post your class code.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/V6hnFEWW

Comment: So by context, you want to pull images from the database, based on some criteria, to display in a template or post correct?

Comment: Yes, the incoming data storing in the database and the $images contain these data. In frontend I would like to "read" $images and write out datas. But I don'T know how to reach $images in the frontend page.

Comment: Can I see the code where you are actually writing the image data to the database?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vs0y8gAY

Comment: OK ... so now you would like to get an object from the **photo_contest_entries** table on the front end correct?

Comment: Yes, I don't know that it's possible to reach the $images, or I create a separately new object in frontend.

Comment: You need to decide on a criteria for display. For example, do you want to display images that have a certain Category ID, Image ID etc. ?

Comment: Not necessary. $images contain all data, if I need criteria  I can write an if (for example if($image->getimgId === 1){...}). I need one object with all data.

Comment: That would tend to get very slow as your images table gets bigger and bigger over time

Comment: No problem, will be used at intervals, after a period its restart with new content and below 100 data.

Comment: So basically you could add [this](https://pastebin.com/AXBUHxG6) to your theme's **functions.php**  and call it from any template with `$images = get_pc_entries();`

Comment: Thanks for Your help. At last I created a new control structure in the frontend index file, where I use the same functions as in the admin side. With this I do the same what You wrote in the get_pc_entries().

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [Jamie-D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2244274/jamie-d), I can solve my problem. I can't reach the original object in admin side, but I created a same structure as in admin and call the same functions. With this I created a new variable for the object, which contain the same data as the original, because both use the same database.